# Parsing booleans in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

The [Robot Framework User Guide, section 6.6 Boolean arguments](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#boolean-arguments), says:

> Many keywords in Robot Framework standard libraries accept arguments
>   that are handled as Boolean values true or false. If such an argument
>   is given as a string, it is considered false if it is either empty or
>   case-insensitively equal to false or no. Other strings are considered
>   true regardless their value, and other argument types are tested using
>   same rules as in Python.

How do I replicate this behavior in my own user keywords?

The build-in keyword `Convert To Boolean` is stricter:

> Converts the given item to Boolean true or false.
>
> Handles strings True and False (case-insensitive) as expected,
>   otherwise returns item's truth value using Python's bool() method.

Comment: are you asking h ow to do it in keywords written in python, or in robot syntax?

Comment: I would prefer Robot syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two functions in robot.utils for dealing with boolean arguments - is_truthy and is_falsy. DateTime uses is_falsy. To behave like that library, you could simple call the same function used by those libraries. Below is an implementation of is_falsy in Robot syntax and en example keyword using it to convert arguments. You could also convert the arguments as needed using the same evaluate statement and avoid inter-dependencies.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Boolean
  [Template]    Some Keyword
  truE
  ${42}
  FAlsE
  no
  ${0}

*** Keywords ***
Some Keyword
    [Arguments]    ${option}
    ${option as bool}    Is Truthy    ${option}
    Log To Console    ${option} -> ${option as bool}

Is Truthy
  [Arguments]    ${arg}
  ${arg as bool}    Evaluate    robot.utils.is_truthy($arg)    modules=robot
  [Return]    ${arg as bool}
```